# How to get file name list from nuxeo folder using rest api?

Tags: rest, file, upload, nuxeo

I upload files to nuxeo document under workspace. Now I need to get file info list using folder UUID. Using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/id/{folder_id}` endpoint I get only folder information, but not files info inside a folder. Which endpoint I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can list documents from folder by `advanced_document_content` page provider like this:

```
curl -X GET -u Administrator:Administrator \
  "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/search/pp/advanced_document_content/execute?currentPageIndex=0&offset=0&pageSize=40&ecm_parentId=b7ffc1a1-5439-4050-9562-bcaa4db0624f&ecm_trashed=false" | jq
```

Where `ecm_parentId` parameter specifies UUID of the folder. You can also use paging (`currentPageIndex`, `offset` and `pageSize` parameters) and when you set `pageSize=0` it will list all folder document.

It will list basic properties for each document. If you need more details about each document you can use `properties` a `enrichers-document` headers, where you can specify what else do you want to be retreived like this:

```
curl -X GET -u Administrator:Administrator \
  -H "properties: dublincore,common,uid,file" \
  -H "enrichers-document: thumbnail, permissions" \
  "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/search/pp/advanced_document_content/execute?currentPageIndex=0&offset=0&pageSize=40&ecm_parentId=b7ffc1a1-5439-4050-9562-bcaa4db0624f&ecm_trashed=false" | jq
```

- `properties` header lists document schemas
- `enrichers-document` header lists content enrichers which provides further information about the document. [Here](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/content-enrichers/) you can find list of all available enrichers or you can implement your custom one.